# How to get list of issues of a repo using Github GraphQL.NET

Tags: github-graphql, octokit.net

According to the documentation, I used this code to build a query:

```
var query = new Query()
.Repository("some_repo", "MuziburRahman")
.Select(r => new
{
    r.Name,
    r.Description,
    Issues = r.Issues(100, null, null, null, null, null, null).Select(i => i.Nodes).Select(i => new
    {
        i.Title,
        i.Body,
    }).ToList(),
});
```

But it shows error: *An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments*.

[image]

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like they added another parameter, so you have to add another `null`.

```
r.Issues(100, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
```